# Official Python GPG Signing Key - Where is it? - gpg: using RSA key FC624643487034E5

Tags: python, security, gnupg

Where can I get a copy of the `GPG/PGP public key` that was used to sign the Python installation files?

The key fingerprint is `"FC624643487034E5"`. (gpg --verify python-3.8.0-amd64.exe.asc python-3.8.0-amd64.exe)

I searched for multiple key stores like [MIT](http://pgp.mit.edu/), [Ubuntu](https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/), and others.

The signature is there with the [download](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-380/).

This is the [signature](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.0/python-3.8.0-amd64.exe.asc).

There are many `.asc` signature files. Somebody should upload the key to a mainline key server, or the signatures are worthless.
https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.0/

RedHat, for example, publishes their security team keys:
https://access.redhat.com/security/team/key/

It's probably overkilling to verify signatures, but the supply-chain attack is real.  Look at what happened to Android:
https://krebsonsecurity.com/2019/06/tracing-the-supply-chain-attack-on-android-2/

Thank you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the public keys for Python release binaries here: [Download Python | Python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/), look for the `OpenPGP Public Keys` section.

The specific key you're looking at (`FC624643487034E5`) belongs to Steve Dower, who's associated with Windows binary releases. Here's a direct link to Steve's public key hosted on `keybase.io`: [7ed10b6531d7c8e1bc296021fc624643487034e5](https://keybase.io/stevedower/pgp_keys.asc?fingerprint=7ed10b6531d7c8e1bc296021fc624643487034e5)